# Keras to pytorch: what makes my model perform differently?

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

Just below I state my model's architecture implemented in Keras:

```
ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6, activation = "relu"))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6, activation = "relu"))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation = "sigmoid"))
ann.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
ann.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 100)
```

This model gives the following confusion matrix where the input data  is of 12 predictors and the target is binary.

```
[[1498   97]
 [ 184  221]]
```

I reimplemented it in pytorch the fllowing way

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,n_inputs):    
        # Define all the parameters of the net
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(n_inputs, 6)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(6, 6)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(6, 1)

    def forward(self, x):    
        # Do the forward pass
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc3(x))
        return x
```

Then I get the following confusion matrix:

```
[[1594    0]
 [ 406    0]]
```

I'm sure I missing something but it seems that my implementation is correct but I don't know what am I missing exactly.

Answer (score 0):

There many things different between Keras and Pytorch, such as kernel initializer, bias initializer, random seed, optimizer's param and your hyperparameters.

For example, reference to both document, keras dense layer's initializer are glorot_uniform and zeros: [Keras Dense](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/)

```
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units,
    activation=None,
    use_bias=True,
    kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
    bias_initializer="zeros",
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    bias_regularizer=None,
    activity_regularizer=None,
    kernel_constraint=None,
    bias_constraint=None,
    **kwargs
)
```

while Pytorch linear's initializer are not:  [Pytorch Linear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html)